# Как добавлять записи во связанные таблицы SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть  у меня 3 таблицы. Они связаны между собой. Я не могу понять принципа как добавлять данные  в таблицу правильно.

```
    CREATE TABLE [Medal](
    [ID_Medal] INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    [name] NTEXT, 
    [ID_Dostizenie] INT REFERENCES Dostizenie([ID_Dostizenie]));


    CREATE TABLE [Dostizenie](
    [ID_Dostizenie] INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    [meta] INT);


    CREATE TABLE [Options](
    [ID_Options] INT, 
    [name_i18n] NTEXT, 
    [ID_Medal] INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Medal([ID_Medal]));
```

Конечно  я могу добавлять вот так

```
    ContentValues contentAll = new ContentValues();
    contentAll.put("name", "Защитник");
    contentAll.put("ID_Dostizenie", 1);
    myDbHelper.setInsert("Medal", null, contentAll); //Записываем данные

   ...
  //Добавление данных
public long setInsert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
{
    return myDataBase.insert(table, nullColumnHack, values);
}
```

Ну как теперь мне заполнить таблицу `Options`, если `ID_Medal` стоит на автоинкременте и я не знаю его значение. Думал как вариант открывать таблицу `Medal` и считывать последнее `ID_Medal` которое там есть. Ну мне кажется это не правильно и есть другой способ.

Comment: Посмотрите в драйвере вашей базы, там наверняка есть метод вроде last_insert_ID(), который возвращает последний использованный автоикрементный id.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, в SQLite insert возвращает ID последней добавленной строки (и -1, если ошибка).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщение содержится намек на решение вопроса, но ответ можно улучшить добавив пример скрипта, вставляющего две записи в две таблицы, связанные внешним ключем.